# WCF. Не передается пользовательский обьект

Tags: .net, объекты, wcf

Пытаюсь передать файлы от WCF сервера клиенту. Файл - это обьект пользовательского класса. Вот так выглядит класс:

```
[DataContract]
public class Fileobject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Lenght { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public FileInfo FInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Запрос происходит в клиенте следующим образом:

```
fileobject.Fileobject file = Client.GetFile(path, ClientInfo.Login);
```

А вот таким образом запрос обрабатывается сервером:

```
public Fileobject GetFile(string path, string login)
    {
        try
        {
            string fpath = Foolpath(path, login);
            Fileobject file = new Fileobject
            {
                FileStream = File.Open(fpath, FileMode.Open),
                FInfo = new FileInfo(fpath),
            };
            file.Lenght = (int)file.FileStream.Length;
            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
            return null;
        }
    }
```

При этом обработка запроса на сервере происходит верно, файл считывается, создается корректный пользовательский обьект типа fileobject, но когда он возвращается вылетает:

*"Ошибка при получении ответа HTTP на http://localhost:58238/FolderSyncService.svc. Возможно, это вызвано тем, что привязка конечной точки службы не использует протокол HTTP. Это может быть также вызвано тем, что контекст запроса HTTP прерван сервером (возможно, из-за отключения службы). Подробнее см. в журналах сервера.""*

В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал передать сам поток (`public Stream FileStream`). Передается без проблем.

Comment: Как вы себе представляете передачу файлового потока внутри XML-тэга?

Comment: Прошу прощения если вопрос детский - студент все таки. Если я правильно понял поток внутри обьекта передать нельзя? Просто я считал что поток такой же обьект как и все остальные. Соответственно и передавать можно так же.

Comment: @P_Soltys: Ну вот вам более простой пример: вы передаёте на другой компьютер _указатель_. На исходном компьютере он указывает на какие-то данные, а на целевом скорее всего в «на кого бог пошлёт». Вы ведь не удивляетесь, что указатель на другой компьютер передать нельзя?

Comment: @P_Soltys: Точно так же и файловый поток ссылается на какой-то файл на своей файловой системе. Если он передастся на «ту сторону», откуда на той стороне возьмётся такой же файл?

Comment: Такие вещи _иногда_ делают при помощи прокси объектов, это да.